No Wi-Fi adapter found in ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS
I am trying to connect to wi-fi, but my system shows no wi-fi adapters found. Also, the wi-fi option disappeared from the quick access tab on the top right. My driver is 'Wi-Fi 6 AX201'.

the current version of Ubuntu 22.04 is 22.04.5 there is no version 22.02

Thanks for noticing.
